# how to tell vi to not to open all the included sudoers?

Tags: sudo

We have many rules/files in `/etc/sudoers.d/`

If we use visudo, vi opens all the files in `sudoers.d/` too.

**Question:** How can we tell `vi`, not to open all the include files, because we only need to open the file that we opened with vi, ex. `/etc/sudoers`, not all the included files.

Answer (score 5):

`visudo --help` shows the `-f` option which allows you to specify the file to open such as:

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: No. Did anyone tried this out? After closing the /etc/sudoers with ":q" it still opens all the included files from sudoers.d .... and it still received 5 points??

Comment: Would you care to show me a `ls -l /etc/sudoers.d`?

Comment: Note that you should use a more cordial attitude.  Do you think I didn't work hard enough on the huge amount of money you gave us?

Comment: but +5 points for a wrong answer? did you tested what have you said? :)

Comment: Yes, but not with your setup which you won't even share with us.  If you need help, give some details on your particular situation or just move on, but lose that attitude already.